# Correct way to pass model instance from middleware to controller?

Tags: laravel

If I have a middleware that fetches a related model from an authenticated *User* (ie: *Info* model), checking stuff and throwing error if an inconsistency is found in *User's Info*, otherwise I want to use that same *Info* in my controller without making the same query again.

I know I can `$request->request->add(['info' => $info])` and then call it as `request('info')` in my controller, but it doesn't seems to be the best way since it's giving me a huge headache when combined with Livewire resulting in weird and unexpected behavior.

So, what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this documentation. [Laravel 8 Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user)

So what it says basically is that once you are authenticated, you can always use **Auth** facade anywhere from your code and get the Info model associated to it (Assuming you have setup the eloquent relationship between your User & Info models)

e.g.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

// MyController.php

public function index(Request $request)
{
   // Let's say Info model has address column
   $address = Auth::user()->info->address;
}
```

Your User model should have relationship with Info Model like this, well then again assuming **Info class** has one to one relationship with your **User class**

Source: [Laravel 8 Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

```
class User extends Authenticatable 
{

    public function info()
    {

        return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\Info::class);
    }
}
```